# How did the Bat-Signal work on cloudless/moonless nights?

Tags: dc, batman

How did the Bat-Signal work on cloudless and moonless nights?

[image: Bat signal]

Comment: On a clear night, did the crime rate go up?

Comment: They used the telephone.

Comment: Its a Bat-Tech, man!

Comment: Or maybe we only see Batman fighting the crime on cloudy nights, but it actually goes on all the time. Woah, man.

Comment: It’s Gotham. It’s always cloudy.

Comment: Not so well. (Take that @Paul)

Comment: What does the moon have to do with any of this? To project the Bat-Signal on the moon, you'd need a *very* powerful light source.

Comment: Has anyone ever made a working Bat-signal in RealLife™?

Comment: The Bat-Signal would shine more brightly on moonless (darker) nights.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because the Bat-signal (being a searchlight, or, in the newer iterations, a laser system) works off of light, it technically couldn't be visible without something to diffuse the light (like clouds or smoke) or reflect the light (like a solid surface). When it is visible without clouds (usually in the animated series), it's simply movie magic.

But the Bat-signal wasn't necessary to contact Batman: when the Bat-signal was otherwise unavailable, the Bat-phone was used:

This was obviously updated for later iterations of Batman, as [Wikipedia describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bat_phone#Batman_comic):

> In the modern Batman comic book continuity, the Batphone made its debut in Detective Comics #786 (November, 2003), in the form of an encrypted cellphone that allowed Gordon to securely contact Batman, as well as allowing other calls just like a normal cellphone. It also carries a tracking device in case of trouble. Unlike the original Batphone, the device is not red and looks like a regular cellphone.